# Where is the controller of Devise ? how to add data from other models in users/edit page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

it seems devise do not create any controller file in app/controller folder, now I am looking to show some custom info from other models in users/edit view but not able to figure out how to do it since there is no controller to add

```
@num_of_cars = current_user.num_of_cars.all
```

I am looking to show num_of_cars in users/edit page but not able to figure out how to do it

EDIT - the below mentioned code giving me error, I am putting this code in my devise/registration/edit file

```
<%= render partial: 'myinfo/cars_list' %>
```

where myinfo is another resource with a partial _cars_list.html.erb, the /myinfo scaffold works perfectly fine but when I am trying to display that partial into users/edit, it is giving me

```
undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass
```

(I am using each_wit_index to display list but I don't think that is the problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the Devise sessions controller actions:

```
# app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def edit
    # add custom logic here
    @num_of_cars = current_user.num_of_cars.all 
    super
  end

end
```

Register the controller:

```
# app/config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions"}
```

Comment: thanks, can you tell me what do you mean by regsiter_the controller ? I thought having the controller code in apps is enough to link to routes ?

Comment: Maybe a call to "super" would be appropriate in some cases in your new controller

Comment: @ChristophGeschwind - Thanks Chris, can you explain me how super will be appropriate ? also why define controllers for :users in routes ?

Comment: @ChristophGeschwind and zeantsoi - Well the above code is giving me error, I am putting this code in my devise/registration/edit file <%= render partial: 'myinfo/cars_list' %> where myinfo is another resource with a partial _cars_list.html.erb, the /myinfo scaffold works perfectly fine but when I am trying to display that partial into users/edit, it is giving me undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass  (I am using each_wit_index to display list but I don't think that is the problem)

Comment: @iCyborg, calling `super` after your variable assignment will enable your action to inherit the properties of the action you're overriding. In this case, it means that your `edit` action will do the same thing as the default Devise `edit` action, but you'll have the `@num_of_cars` instance variable available to your view as well.

Comment: @iCyborg, you need to register the controller in your routes to tell Rails that you've created a new controller that's supposed to override the corresponding Devise controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can create new controller for handel `devise/registration/edit`

here's is `controller/passwords_controller.rb`

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def edit
    @num_of_cars = current_user.num_of_cars.all
    super
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    # raise params.inspect
    if @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
      sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
      redirect_to user_path, :notice => "Password has been change!"
    else
      render :edit,:locals => { :resource => @user, :resource_name => "user" }
    end
  end
end
```

here's is routes.rb

```
devise_scope :user do
 get '/edit_password' => 'passwords#edit', :as => :change_password
 put '/change' =>  'passwords#update'
end
```

and finaly you can copy `devise/registrations/edit.html.erb` to `passwords/edit.html.erb`

Comment: Thanks for replying, there is something going wrong in the code as I am getting undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass - when I am tryin to render the partial in other views folder

Comment: I am trying to run a test code, in devise/registrations/edit.html.erb I have <%= render partial: 'car_list' %>, in devise/registartion/_car_list.html.erb, I have <%= @ test_var %> 456 and in app/controllers/session_controller.rb, I have edit method with @ test_var = 123, but when I view /users/edit it is only showing 456 and NOT reading 123 (the variable that I have set in controller), any idea what am I doing wrong ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you dont have to override the devise controller. You can replace

```
<%= render partial: 'myinfo/cars_list' %>
```

with

```
<%= render partial: 'myinfo/cars_list', :locals => { :num_of_cars => current_user.num_of_cars.all } %>
```

in your devise/registration/edit page. Then using "num_of_cars" variable instead of "@num_of_cars", inside your 'myinfo/cars_list' partial, should fix your issue.

Comment: I am trying to run a test code, in devise/registrations/edit.html.erb I have <%= render partial: 'car_list' %>, in devise/registartion/_car_list.html.erb, I have <%= @ test_var %> 456 and in app/controllers/session_controller.rb, I have edit method with @ test_var = 123, but when I view /users/edit it is only showing 456 and NOT reading 123 (the variable that I have set in controller), any idea what am I doing wrong ? thanks

Comment: You are setting the value in "app/controllers/session_controller.rb" and edit will be refering to "app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb's edit method". As you are setting in wrong controller action, it is considering "@test_var" as nil and hence, not displaying anything. You can check in server log(terminal), to see which controller action, your request is going to.

Comment: Prem, Thanks for replying, but there is no registraion_controller as I am using @zeantsoi method above of devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions"}, is this not the right way ?

Comment: As per my idea, that variable(@num_of_cars) will only be available if you override "registraions_controller". If this is the only thing you want to use, you can just pass that value from view(devise/registrations/edit) as local variable to the partial, as i mentioned above.