# Instance variable in partial view

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I have a navbar that is a partial view that I need to render on a devise page for the user to edit their profile.  As it is, I only have one page, but adding the path to perform account maintenance has messed up my navbar loading because of the instance variable not being present.  How can I get a global instance variable that works across the board for my navbar, no matter what?

**application_helper.rb**

```
def get_company
  @company = current_user.company
end

def get_locations(company)
  @locations = if @company
    current_user.company_locations.order(:name)
  else
    []
  end
end
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
def home
  @company = get_company
  @locations = get_locations(@company)
  @reports = if @company
    @company.reports.order("created_at DESC").limit(5)
  else
    []
  end
end
```

**views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "pages/navigation" %>
... devise form ....
```

**pages/_navigation.html.erb**

```
<li class="right-menu-item">
      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle " type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <% if @company %>
          <%= @company.name %>
        <% else %>
          <%= current_user.email %>
        <% end %>
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <% @locations.each do |location| %>
          <li role="presentation">
            <%= link_to root_path(location_id: location.id), role: "menuitem", tabindex: "-1" do %>
              <%= image_tag "check-green.svg" if location == @location %>
              <span><%= location.name %></span>
            <% end %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
```

**Where the issue lies:**
[image]

What am I missing here to get this working across all views?

Thanks!

Comment: You're calling `get_company` with an argument when it doesn't accept one. Are you sure this is the right code? All I see is code for your `home` action, and nothing for `edit`.

Comment: Sorry @tadman you're right.  I did take out the current_user argument from passing in pages_controller as I was posting this.  I'm on my phone now, otherwise I'd edit.  It's now '@company = get_company'

Comment: Still pretty sure none of that code is running as the action in the controller does not match the view name.

Comment: I think that's my problem, hence the question.  The devise view is outside of pages_controller which is why '@locations' is kicking the problem in the partial view once it's being rendered.  Is there a way to make the instance variable accessibly from across the board no matter what view I'm in and controller is being called?

Comment: Instance variables defined in controllers are available to all views regardless of file location. What I'm saying is you need to make those names the same, pick one of either `edit` or `home`. If you have a method called `home`, Rails will load the view for `edit` and render it without calling that, so none of your variables are defined. Make the names match if you're looking to have the controller *control* the associated view.

Comment: So I need to add something to the devise edit method for my user?  Sorry... New to devise.

Comment: I think this is the similar problem I'm facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965127/where-is-the-controller-of-devise-how-to-add-data-from-other-models-in-users-e so I have to override the devise controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems that [Where is the controller of Devise ? how to add data from other models in users/edit page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965127/where-is-the-controller-of-devise-how-to-add-data-from-other-models-in-users-e) was helpful.  I had to do the following to make this work in the partial for the devise views:

`rails g devise:controllers users -c registrations`

which made a registrations controller under **controllers/users/registrations.rb**, then i was able to add the instance variables I needed do the `edit` method:

```
def edit
  @company = get_company
  @locations = get_locations(@company)
end
```

Had to also change the **route.rb** file around a little to facilitate the new controller:

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions],
                   controllers: {
                     registrations: 'users/registrations'
                   }
```